# sql query to check whether multiple entries exist

Tags: mysql, query

I have a table with the following fileds.Here table name is det

```
Name ID
A     1
B     2
C     1
D     3
```

I need a querry to check if multiple entry of name is there for single id. Here iam expecting result like

```
Name ID
A     1
c     1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT Name, ID, COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) cnt
              FROM source_table )
SELECT Name, ID
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM source_table t1
JOIN source_table t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                    AND t1.Name != t2.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select t1.* 
from t1 
inner join 
( select name 
  from t1 
  group by name 
  having count( id ) > 1 
) t2 
on t1.name = t2.name 
order by 1 ;
```

If course, the *better* way to handle this would be to *prevent* the duplicates getting in there in the first place.  :-)